# Как привести набор символов 25032018 к виду 25.03.2018?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$str = 'Дата от 20.05.2022 до 12.06.2022';
$str2 = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    if (is_numeric($str[$i])) {
        $str2 = $str2 . $str[$i];
        $str_data = explode(' ', preg_replace('/\G\d{8}/', "$0 ", $str2));
    }
}
```

Задача в том, что в зависимости от даты нужно показать какой день недели.

Comment: Не понимаю к чему эти извращения с циклом и форматом дат, можно было бы обойтись `preg_match_all('~\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}~', $str, $matches); print_r($matches[0]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat) разбирает строку с датой согласно указанному формату

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY','25032018');
echo $dt->format('d.m.Y'); // 25.03.2018
```